# How to set a Delay on imageSwitcher image change (Android)

Tags: android, delay

I'm working on a menu for my app that is made of a Gallery and sliding it I select a different background image.

```
 gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Gallery.OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
     int arg2, long arg3) {

    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imm[arg2]);
```

The idea works decently but the sliding effect is not fluid.
My idea is to set a delay, setting:

```
imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imm[arg2]);
```

only after a *200ms* or so...
is something like this possible?

Thank you :)
Marco

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Timer and TimerTask class to schedule a operation to happen every 200ms

Something like

```
Timer scrollTimer = new Timer();
scrollTimer.schedule(
    new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        runOnUiThread(Call the method to do ur work);
    }
},
0,200);
```